# Trying to Compile FreeRtos for Riscv .Error: Instruction csrr requires absolute expression

Tags: linux, freertos, riscv

i am trying to compile the FreeRTOS riscv_spike port, with riscv32-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc toolchain but got his error

Error:
../../Source/portable/GCC/RISCV/port.c:121: Error: Instruction csrr requires absolute expression

The following code is from port.c of freeRtos Source

```
    __asm volatile("csrr t0,mtime");
    __asm volatile("add t0,t0,%0" :: "r"(configTICK_CLOCK_HZ/configTICK_RATE_HZ));
    __asm volatile("csrw mtimecmp,t0");
```

can anyone describe me what changes i need to make?
i guess the mtime, mtimecmp is invalid
can i add this required definition in "encoding" file by reading the spec?

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [riscv-privildged-v1.10](https://content.riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/riscv-privileged-v1.10.pdf) in § 3.1.15, mtime & mtimecmp are exposed as a memory-mapped machine-mode register. They are accessed by store (`sw`) and load instructions (`lw`), and not by `csr*` instructions.

They are therefore platform implementation dependent - in particular their address depend on the platform.

Your code cannot be assembled because the `csrr` & `csrw` expect both a value and not a relocatable expression as you have written. But as mentionned at the beginning, you have to use sw and lw instructions - and take care that mtime & mtimecmp are implemented and at which address they can be accessed.

Comment: hi, what about mtohost and fromhost ??

Comment: I do not know what mtohost and fromhost are. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: they are also registers like mtime and mtimecmp, i think the same procedure which you mentioned applies for mtohost and fromhost ?You can refer the previous version architecture.Can you give me any example, how i can achieve that using lw and sw instruction?

Comment: You can have a look at https://github.com/padmaraob/FreeRTOS-RISCV/blob/master/Source/portable/GCC/RISCV/port.c which does not need to use __asm to manipulate mtime & mtimecmp (memory mapped reg). Regarding mtohost & fromhost, if they are memory mapped, you just have to do the same.

Comment: Now understood how i can do it. Do you know when compiling the source it needs encoding.h file, which file in the toolchain, i must copy to the source folder when compiling the Demo source

Comment: to my understanding, encoding.h is for spike, not for FreeRTOS. But I may be wrong.